# Pick subset of functions as string & evaluate

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, function

I have a set of defined JS functions. I want users to pick a subset of these using a comma separated string. Then I want to randomly pick from their subset, and evaluate the function selected. I have this 99% working, except it is not evaluating for some reason. Why does console keep telling me 'undefined is not a function'?

Take a peek at line 37: http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/

```
// 1 User picks a subset of function names as a comma seperated string.
var effectSubset = 'func4, func5, func6';


// 2 Available functions
    function func1() {
        $('html').append('func1');
    }

    function func2() {
        $('html').append('func2');
    }

    function func3() {
        $('html').append('func3');
    }

    function func4() {
        $('html').append('func4');
    }

    function func5() {
        $('html').append('func3');
    }

    function func6() {
        $('html').append('func4');
    }


var autoPlay = function () {
    // 3 Get the user's subset of functions, turn into array
    effectArray = effectSubset.split(',');
    // 4 Pick random function from array
    var effect = effectArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * effectArray.length)];
    // 5 run the randomly picked function
    window[effect]();
}

// 6 Re-run every second
var playInterval = setInterval(autoPlay, 1000);
```

Comment: ` window[effect]();` which window are you referring to here ?

Comment: In trying to figure this out, I saw that was suggested to run a string as a function, but I don't think it's working because it's within a function.

Comment: your functions are not in the window object here. so you can do like this window[func1] = function (){}; window.func1 = function (){}; add them to window object and try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see two things wrong:

1. Your functions were not assigned to the `window`
2. Your `"effect"` variable contained leading whitespace

I have corrected the above points here: http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/1/

This appears to have resolved the issue you described.

**Example:**

```
window.func1 = function() {
    $('html').append('func1');
}
```

**And:**

```
window[effect.trim()]();
```

---

**Update**

As a bonus I fixed your misleading append messages =D

http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/5/

Comment: Quick question, in the full application, I'm using this function on several elements, and am actually appending to the individual elements rather than the html tag. I have set a var of 'that' equal to 'this' to maintain the scope of 'this', but it seems the window method messes that up, is that right? All of the appending just goes into the last element rather than each one now.

Comment: As long as the scope of `this` (or `that`) is available to you when you are both assigning the functions and calling the functions, you will be fine.  `window` had the convenience of naturally being available in both cases hence worked.  Ill take a look at the fiddle :)

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle of what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/6/  I probably should've included this info in the original question, but I was trying to keep it as simplified as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've completely understood the minutiae of your wider objectives, but I have amended a fiddle to use the `that` variable instead of window.  http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/7/

Comment: Thank you! This updated jsfiddle shows me exactly what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is not working because you have a space between the function names 
`var effectSubset = 'func4, func5, func6';` After split the variable effect has a space before the name of the functions.

So the functions being called are `func4`, `<space>func5`, `<space>func6` with a space which do not exist.

Firstly, its better to have a namespace.

```
var effectSubset = 'func4,func5,func6'; // <--- remove spaces here or trim like in other answers
window.myNamespace = {};

window.myNamespace.func1 = function() {
    $('html').append('func1');
}
// ..... define other functions like above
window["myNamespace"][effect](); // <-- this should work
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/lixeto/edit?html,js,output**

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues: first there are leading whitespaces after you split the input and second, JSFiddle is wrapping your script in an IIFE. The first issue can be solved by either splitting with ' ,' or mapping the resulting array with a trim function. The second issue can be solved by creating an object to assign the functions to. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftaq8q4m/3/) for a working example.

```
// 1 User picks a subset of function names as a comma seperated string.
var effectSubset = 'func4, func5, func6';


// 2 Available functions
var funcObj = {
    func1: function func1() {
        $('html').append('func1');
    },

    func2: function func2() {
        $('html').append('func2');
    },

    func3: function func3() {
        $('html').append('func3');
    },

    func4: function func4() {
        $('html').append('func4');
    },

    func5: function func5() {
        $('html').append('func3');
    },

    func6: function func6() {
        $('html').append('func4');
    }
};

var autoPlay = function () {
    // 3 Get the user's subset of functions, turn into array
    effectArray = effectSubset.split(',').map(function(func) { return func.trim() });
    // 4 Pick random function from array
    var effect = effectArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * effectArray.length)];
    // 5 run the randomly picked function
    funcObj[effect]();
}

// 6 Re-run every second
var playInterval = setInterval(autoPlay, 1000);
```